# Find functions has a given propertiy

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, exponential-function

Find a function
$f:(0, \infty) \rightarrow(1, \infty)$ (not necessary continuos)  satisfying that for each sequence $\left\{\mathrm{t}_{n}\right\} \subset(0, \infty), \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f\left(\mathrm{t}_{n}\right)=1$ if and only if $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} t_{n}=0^{+}$.
" I know that exponential has this property but i want another examples "

Comment: At least every one-to-one map such that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x)=1$ will do the trick.

Comment: $1/(1+x^2), x^2 + 1, x^3 + 1, \dots$ the list in endless.

Comment: thank you so much, that means i can take $ f(x)=ln(x+e) $.